# Overwriting a SpringBoot class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot app with its class:

```
Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class TdkApplication  implements CommandLineRunner {
...
}
```

that I want to extend to overwrite a method

```
public class MyTdkApplication extends TdkApplication {

}
```

But I can't run this class as a Java application

Comment: Why do you need to extend it and not favour composition instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make **TdkApplication** as an abstract class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public abstract class TdkApplication  implements CommandLineRunner {    }



public class MyTdkApplication extends TdkApplication {
 SpringApplication.run(MyTdkApplication .class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }}
```